# if statement not behaving as expected...(I blame netbeans)

Tags: java

my code is this.

```
x = 500;
if (x > 0 && x < 100 );
 {
System.out.println(" x is " + x);
 }
```

for some reason netbeans is deciding to run the stuff in the if statement even though it shouldn't because 500 > 100. at this point I'm blaming netbeans for not running my code properly xD

Comment: Remove the semicolon after the `if` condition.

Comment: I general, when something looks pretty basic like this, it's probably safe to assume that the bug is in your understanding of the code, and not in Netbeans/Eclipse/JVM/unicorns/whatever. There is a very small chance that `if` conditions, simple `&&`s, or int comparisons would be broken in a tool that's over a decade old and as frequently used as Netbeans.

Answer (score 3):

The single semi-colon is an "empty statement" which in combination with Java's allowance of if statements without {} blocks makes a perfect storm.

Netbeans is not to blame, this time.

This is actually what you passing to the compiler..

```
x = 500;
if (x > 0 && x < 100 ) {
   ; // <== do nothing
}

{ // <== anonymous block
   System.out.println(" x is " + x);
}
```

Code-quality tools like [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) will catch errors like these. It's the [EmptyStatement rule](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html) in Checkstyle.